# iOS - use device camera to recognise a 3D object

Tags: ios, iphone, camera, augmented-reality

I'm developing an app that makes use of an augmented reality feature whereby the user can point the device's camera at a point of interest such as a building and get information on that building.

**Are there any frameworks out there for the *iOS SDK* that allow for this functionality?**

I've looked at the *Vuforia framework*, however this doesn't seem to support this feature.
If anyone could point me in the right direction I'd appreciate it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can put some markers on the buildings, you can try [ARToolKit](http://www.hitl.washington.edu/artoolkit/download/).

If you cannot, it will be a much more difficult problem.
If the buildings look similar, it is impossible to distinguish them by their appearance.
If they look very different, you may try feature detection techniques such as [SIFT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale-invariant_feature_transform) or [SURF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SURF).

GPS information will make your job easier, if you know the exact location of these buildings.